# Ubuntu iso image - different size when downloading via torrent or from ubuntu.com

Tags: iso

Ubuntu 16.4.1 iso size 1Gb on ubuntu site. but when I download via torrent it seems iso size 1.5 GB. which one should I download?

Torrent: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Ubuntu site: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute?version=16.04.1&architecture=amd64

Comment: Can you please describe in detail (e.g. add a link) to the two files you would like to compare? Probably you look at different editions (e.g. server and desktop or 32 and 64 bit).

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent this is 1.5 GB

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute?version=16.04.1&architecture=amd64

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the formal size limit for Ubuntu releases. On paper, the release ISOs may not be larger than 1 GB. But in reality, the last few releases did not observe that limit and were larger. The ISO image for the desktop edition of Ubuntu 16.04 is around 1.4 GB to 1.5 GB, so your number sounds about right. The `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent` should be the correct one. There already is a discussion to raise the formal size limit. For further information, see for example [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/ubuntu-image-size-increase-2gb).

Comment: Both downloads should point to the same version and should be equally correct.

Comment: But size is different

Comment: So torrent will be best to me

Comment: Have a look on the article linked below the download that tells you how to verify your download. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the article linked below the download that tells you how to verify the isos: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify
If one of those images was tampered with you can prove it this way.